# python mysqldb table updates not working

Tags: python, mysql

I'm a python noob and am having trouble with a MySQLdb operation to update a table after I've done some sentiment analysis with VADER.  The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import MySQLdb as my
try:
    db = my.connect(host="*",    
                    user="*",         
                    passwd="*",  
                    db="*")        
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id,content FROM text where relscore >=100")
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        tableid = row[0]
        textin = row[1].rstrip('\n') + ' '
        sentences = sent_tokenize(textin)
        analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
        sum = 0
        count = 0
        for sentence in sentences:
            vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
            count += 1
            sum += vs['compound']
        avg = sum / count
        cur.execute("update text set sentiment = %s where id = %s",(avg,tableid))
    db.close()

 except my.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

When I ran this without the try/except, it would run as expected without errors, but the values did not get updated in the db.  I added the try/except to try to access any error coming from mysql, but I am getting a syntax error with that

```
     except my.Error as e:
                         ^
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I don't get that because it seems to match the indentation level of the try, and it looks like examples I have found.  But like I said I'm a noob so I'm probably missing something obvious.

I have verified with a debugger that the select statement is working and avg is being calculated, and have verified that the user has the necessary privileges on the db and table.  Can anyone help out?

Comment: There is a space before except my.Error as e:. Remove and test it again

Answer (score -1):

You must commit your changes after executing queries (before closing your cursor):

```
cur.commit()
db.close()
```

As for `try...except` block: you have extra space before `except` word.

Comment: Ok.  Apprently it has to be db.commit though.  That made it work.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have a space before except my.Error as e:

Remove it and retest

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import MySQLdb as my
try:
    db = my.connect(host="*", user="*", passwd="*", db="*")        

    cur = db.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT `id`, `content` FROM text WHERE `relscore`>=100")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        tableid = row[0]
        textin = row[1].rstrip('\n') + ' '
        sentences = sent_tokenize(textin)
        analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
        sum = 0
        count = 0

        for sentence in sentences:
            vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
            count += 1
            sum += vs['compound']

        avg = sum / float(count)

        cur.execute("UPDATE text SET `sentiment` = %s WHERE `id` = %s", (avg,tableid))

    db.commit()
    cur.close()
    db.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```